# Regular Expression to not allow 3 consecutive characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}/(.)$");

(?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case
(?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}       //should contain at least 8 characters and maximum of 20
```

My problem is I also need to check if 3 consecutive characters are identical. Upon searching, I saw this solution:

```
/(.)\1\1/
```

However, I can't make it to work if I combined it to my existing regex, still no luck:

```
Regex(@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$/(.)\1\1/");
```

What did I missed here? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like C#, not JavaScript.

Comment: This is clearly password validation. You shouldn't restrict your users like this.

Comment: This is the requirements for the password strength.

Comment: @Gerald: tell to whoever created that guideline that it's silly

Comment: "However, I can't make it to work if I combined it to my existing regex" --- there is nothing wrong to have multiple regexes.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this in a regex, or at least one that's not very long.  You're better off writing some code that loops through the string.

Comment: A downvote for just following requirements?

Comment: Go check your passwords in a second `/(.)\1\1/` run.

Comment: @zerkms I think I will do that. I will do that then update this post. Thanks!

Comment: You know that your regex only allows English letters and numbers, right? No dashes, periods, or other characters are allowed.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, I am aware of it. I will do it one by one. As of now, I am searching on how to include only selected special characters.

Comment: @remyabel I see password requirements on websites all the time, why is it not a good idea? I can see that there's a usability argument that can be made against it, but at the same time, it's not in your users' best interest to make passwords with insufficient complexity, in terms of security. These rules aren't ***that*** restrictive, I've seen requirements on some websites that are borderline absurd, like forcing users to change passwords every few months. Then again, things like password databases make remembering complex passwords unnecessary, and changing them less of a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by using trial and error:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$");
```

Comment: Excellent. Good for you!

Comment: @Gabe Can I use the `(?!.*(.)\1\1)` on javascript language?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `/(.)\1\1/` includes the surrounding `/` characters which are used to quote literal regular expressions in some languages (like Perl). But even if you don't use the quoting characters, you can't just add it to a regular expression.

At the beginning of your regex, you have to say "What follows cannot contain a character followed by itself and then itself again", like this: `(?!.*(.)\1\1)`. The `(?!` starts a *zero-width negative lookahead assertion*. The "zero-width" part means that it does not consume any characters in the input string, and the "negative lookahead assertions" means that it looks forward in the input string to make sure that the given pattern does not appear anywhere.

All told, you want a regex like this:

```
new Regex(@"^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,20}$")
```

Comment: I posted an answer, same with yours at the same time :) Thanks for the explanation and making it clear to me!